# Samba and usbmount: can't write on automounted device

Tags: usb, networking, samba, root

This is my problem:

I configured my RPi with Debian:

- Samba shares a specific folder, that is readable-writeable-executable from my home network: `/media/`
- `usbmount` automount USB devices when inserted in my RPi, in `/media/usb`
- No users should be logged in to do this

When I insert an USB device, usbmount mount it correctly, so RPi can write on it and a person can READ it through network.
BUT no persons are allowed to WRITE on it through network.

Checking permissions on `/media/usb` I found that:

- BEFORE usbmount mount device `/media/usb` is `rwx-rwx-rwx`
- AFTER usbmount mount device `/media/usb` became `rwx-r-r`, so only `root` (usbmount work mounting devices as root) can write on it

So I've tryed to change the `FS_MOUNTPOINTS=""` line in `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf` file but I don't know how to force usbmount to automount devices `rwx-rwx-rwx` or with "low-user write permission".

Comment: Check the `MOUNTOPTIONS` entry in `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`. Does it contain `ro`?

Comment: No it doesen't contain `ro`.
All the line: `MOUNTOPTIONS="sync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of test i edited the `FS_MOUNTOPTIONS` line:

```
FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="-fstype=vfat,umask=0000"
```

Where

- `vfat` is the filesystem
- `umask=0000` is the permission of the file and folder. `0000` means `rwx-rwx-rwx`

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem on linux once. It turned out that mounting a drive will apply the root directory permissions to the mount point. A simple `chmod 777 /media/usb` *after* mounting should fix it.

You might also want to add `,dmask=000,fmask=000` (or preferably `002` and using a group) to the `FS_MOUNTOPTIONS` line.

Comment: The Raspberry should do it automatically, without a person that change the permission. However `chmod` doesn't work.